# C compiler error with a lookup table in a .c file

Tags: c, lookup-tables

Below is the contents of a c file. I am generating a lookup table, and when test.c, and when I try to compile it into a test program, I get the following error:

```
In file included from test.c:1:
lut.h:1: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âvaluesâ
```

Does anyone have any insight into this error? I'm trying to have this lookup table included as a .c file for use. (I wouldn't choose to do it this way, but it's a requirement).

```
        static const int16_t values[] = 
        {
            29, 30, 31
        };
```

The test program I am using (just to test compilation) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lut.h"
int main ()
{
    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile with:

```
gcc test.c
```

Comment: It looks like the error has something to do with `getTableValue`, so that's what we need to see. Please be courteous and remove or fix the text encoding errors from the copy-pasted code.

Comment: @NishithJainMR Depending on the dialect of C, a trailing comma may be acceptable. But it is a good suggestion.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I thought of suggesting the same. But removed the comment as it was not to the point.

Comment: Sorry about the bad copy-paste. I've updated it. getTableValue was a function I threw in there in testing and have since deleted.

Comment: Where is int16_t defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this problem. I have in `lut.h`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

static const int16_t values[] = {
  29, 30, 31
};
```

and in `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lut.h"

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", values[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

and I get:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
30
```

Can you provide more info? Maybe copy-paste *exactly* what your `lut.h` looks like?

Comment: The hours are clearly taking a toll. I had #include <stdint.h> in my test.c but not in lut.h. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `int16_t`.  Try including `stdint.h`